# Javascript LocalStorage Null Bug

Tags: javascript, null, local-storage

I'm saving elements in the localstorage like this (using strict mode):

`localStorage.setItem(String(index), JSON.stringify([name, score]));`

Then I wrote a method checking if a new score is bigger than the saved ones:

```
    // Returns index where to place the score and return -1 if no new highscore
    function isHighScore(score) {
    console.log("called");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (localStorage.getItem(String(i)) == null) {
            return i; // No highscore yet at this position => new Highscore
        }
        else{
            var indexObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(String(i)));
            console.log(indexObject);
            if(indexObject[1] < score){ // Checking if new score is higher than currently at this index
                return i; // Returning index if new highscore
            }
        }
    }
    return -1; // checked all entries no new highscore
}
```

But I get this following output (after saving example with name="name" and score= 0):

> called
>
> ["name", 0]
>
> null
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `1` of null

How can this happen? I'm already checking if the value is `null` so how can this pass the first if check `localStorage.getItem(String(i)) == null)`?

Comment: Can you update the question with a [mcve]? (Sadly it'll have to be a non-runnable one, since Stack Snippets don't let you use local storage, though you can make a runnable jsFiddle and link to it **provided** you also include all the code in the question.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok I will do this

Comment: For next time. No need in this case as it happened! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect if you use the browser's devtools to look at what's in local storage, you'll find an entry for `"1"` with the value `"null"`.

That explains the symptoms, because

```
if (localStorage.getItem(String(i)) == null) {
```

...is `false` if `localStorage.getItem(String(i))` returns `"null"`, but then

```
var indexObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(String(i)));
```

...will set `indexObject` to `null`.

Comment: awesome, just fixed it :)